# EntityFramework AutoDetectChangesEnabled disabled and facing issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following request in my repository :

```
public void UpdateAgreementAfterTerme(AgreementTerme agreement)
{
    var agreementData = _agreementContext.Set<T_INSURANCE_AGREEMENT>()
        .Include(f => f.T_COVERAGE_COMPONENT)
        .SingleOrDefault(agg => agg.IDENTIFIER == agreement.Identifier && agg.IS_LAST_VERSION == true);

    if (agreementData?.T_COVERAGE_COMPONENT == null || agreementData.T_COVERAGE_COMPONENT.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var coverageComponent in agreementData.T_COVERAGE_COMPONENT.Where(coverage => coverage.HT_AMOUNT != null))
    {
        coverageComponent.HT_AMOUNT = coverageComponent.HT_AMOUNT * agreement.Coefficient;
    }

    _agreementContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The `T_INSURANCE_AGREEMENT` has a list of `T_COVERAGE_COMPONENT` and I need to update the `HT_AMOUNT` with a coefficient of majoration.

When I disabled the `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` in my context, my unit tests shows me that the `HT_AMOUNT` is not updated. When the varaible is true, it is working fine.

What is wrong in my repository and how can I do it better ?
If you have a better way to loop over the `T_COVERAGE_COMPONENT` list than with a `foreach`, i'm interested

Comment: Lots of good info on `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` [here](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/12/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-3-switching-off-automatic-detectchanges/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the `_agreementContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` before the `SaveChanges()` in order to notify the _context that something has changed

Answer (score 0):

Because you disabled AutoDetectChangesEnabled  you have to explicitly inform the context which entity is being changed and how.
Update your foreach loop with this:

```
 foreach (var coverageComponent in agreementData.T_COVERAGE_COMPONENT.Where(coverage => coverage.HT_AMOUNT != null))
{
    coverageComponent.HT_AMOUNT = coverageComponent.HT_AMOUNT * agreement.Coefficient;
    _agreementContext.Entry(coverageComponent).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Comment: Is it better than adding `_agreementContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` before saving ?

Comment: @XavierW. I am not sure about this. This case is simple, you change a property value. But if the operations get a bit more complex, for example changing a foreign key value then the magic happening inside Entity Framework gets harder to replicate step by step. So I guess it is safer to use .DetectChanges().